# No attribute constant in tensorflow object

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I have completed the installation for tensorflow as per the steps on the website.

In the end, when I have to test the installation

```
import tensorflow  as tf
```

The above line gets interpreted with no errors but when I use

```
tf.constant ('hello')
```

It gives a traceback and an error stating that tensorflow  has no attribute named constant.

I am using a Mac OSX with Python 3.

Comment: *The above line gets interpretted with no errors* **which above line ?**

Comment: After `import tensorflow as tf`, can you print the value of `dir(tf)` and add it to your question?

Comment: Did you install tensorflow-gpu?

Answer (score 2):

Run the python script from your **Tensorflow virtual environment** if you have installed one. All the Tensorflow related modules and attributes are provided separately there.

To activate the virtualenv, use:

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

Answer (score -1):

For tensorflow, keep in mind that you have to first build your graph and then execute it. So, in your case, the `tf.constant('hello')`will not be executed until you call it from your session.
Here's a working example:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
In [2]: tf.constant('hello')
Out[2]: <tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=() dtype=string>

In [3]: c = tf.constant('hello')
In [4]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [5]: sess.run(c)
Out[5]: 'hello'
```

As you can notice, we can have the actual value of `c` on run time.